# DBMS_OUTPUT in Toad on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, oracle, plsql, toad, dbms-output

I am writing a PL/SQL stored procedure using Toad in Eclipse.  I have it working just fine and the procedure is below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE crl_sync
IS

    unit_separator CONSTANT char:= CHR(31);
    record_separator CONSTANT char:= CHR(30);

    CURSOR c_bc is
        SELECT m.barcode, s.id, s.tracking_tags 
        FROM model m, sample s 
        WHERE m.id = s.id;
        r_bc c_bc%ROWTYPE;

BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE(1000000);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('--CRL_SYNC--');
    OPEN c_bc;
    LOOP
        FETCH c_bc into r_bc;
        EXIT WHEN c_bc%NOTFOUND;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('barcode = '||r_bc.barcode);
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE c_bc;
END;
/
```

It compiles and executes just fine; note the DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE line and the put_line at the start to rule out a problem with the query but still nothing in the toad window in Eclipse.  Can someone please provide a pointer as to what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you enable output? Maybe this covers your problem: http://www.toadworld.com/products/toad-extension-for-eclipse/f/42/t/5631.aspx

Comment: thanks but that doesn't show how to enable output :(

Comment: You are correct - it is the 'bulb' icon!  I can't give you credit ona comment though - answer and I'll credit you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[To show this question as answered]

Try the recommendation on [this page](http://www.toadworld.com/products/toad-extension-for-eclipse/f/42/t/5631.aspx):

> There are two editors for Oracle, called "SQL Worksheet" and "Stored
>   Procedure Editor", you can open them with icons in the Connections
>   View. DBMS Output view works with SQL WORKSHEET. So, go to the DBMS
>   output view and enable it with the "bulb" icon. Now, open the SQL
>   Worksheet.